# Apply blur to transparent popup view, swift

Tags: swift, uiview, popup, blur

I have a popup view appear to the user displaying some information, currently the frame for the view is a black, semi transparent box. I want to apply some blur to this box to improve the clarity of what is presented to the user.

I have this code:

### UPDATED

```
class PinDetails : UIView {

    var popupView:UIView!
    var txtName:UITextField!
    var img1:UIButton!
    var img2:UIButton!
    var img3:UIButton!
    var selectedIndex:Int!
    var dictLocation:[String:String]!

    var blur:UIBlurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light)

    override init(frame: CGRect) {

        super.init(frame: frame)

        var effectView:UIVisualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView (effect: blur)
        effectView.frame = frame
        addSubview(effectView)

        popupView =  UIView(frame:TCRectMake(x: 25,y: 120,width: 270,height: 285))
        popupView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        popupView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white:0, alpha: 0.5)
        self.addSubview(popupView)
```

The blur code I tried to implement doesnt seem to work, xcode states:
`instance member 'blur' cannot be used on type 'PinDetails`.

Any help appreciated, I am fairly new to Swift :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try placing your

```
var effectView:UIVisualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView (effect: blur)
effectView.frame = frame
addSubview(effectView)
```

Inside init(). You are using properties which are not yet initialized.

-- Update --

I'd recommmend using the frame for the Popupview you create to create the visualeffectview. Try this in your init()

```
    // Create the popup view
    popupView =  UIView(frame:CGRectMake(25,120,270,285))
    popupView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    popupView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white:0, alpha: 0.5)

    // Create the Effect View and apply to Popup view
    let effect = UIVisualEffectView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,popupView.layer.frame.width, popupView.layer.frame.height))
    effect.effect = blur
    popupView.addSubview(effect)

    // Add the popupview to the main view
    self.addSubview(popupView)
```

Comment: I applied your change however the blur covers almost all the screen instead of the black box, which hovers above a map view :( Any suggestions? I want the blur to be specifically attached to the box

Comment: This seems to apply it specifically to the window which is good :) Only issue now is that the cornerRadius code doesnt seem to function, is there any way to apply this to the blurred window?

Comment: Popupview.layer.maskstobounds = true

Comment: Perfect! Thanks :D

Comment: One last thing if you can help, do you have any idea how to get drop shadow to work? I cant seem to get it to function especially with the last line you posted

Comment: Could you maybe provide a code sample of what you currently use? That would help :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116281/discussion-between-emptyless-and-james-patterson).